# How to check if the current connection is in a transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transaction

I need my program code to ensure that certain part of logic is being executed within a transaction.

What query would tell me the current transaction ID  / other information that would allow me to determine if I am in a transaction from within the transaction?

```
BEGIN;
-- How to check if I am in a transaction?
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way is to compare [`now()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to [`statement_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

- `now()` gives the current date and time (start of current transaction).
- `statement_timestamp()` gives the current date and time (start of current statement).

Example:

```
SELECT now() = statement_timestamp();
-- TRUE

BEGIN;
SELECT now() = statement_timestamp();
-- FALSE
```

The other alternative is to execute two queries:

```
SELECT txid_current();
SELECT txid_current();
```

and compare the resulting xid. If it is the same, then you are in a transaction.

The downside to the latter approach is that every [`txid_current()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) increments xid value and will further advance you to a [wraparound](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html).

Comment: +1 In Postgres 14 you can use `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()` to avoid/delay the downside of consuming xid values.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. 
```BEGIN;
SELECT now() = statement_timestamp();
```
returns TRUE if submitted in a single batch.

Comment: Same for me - this method only works if the `BEGIN`  and the `SELECT` are run in separate batches.

Answer (score 7):

From PostgreSQL version 10 and onward (i.e., *all* supported versions as of May, 2022), there is, besides the `txid_current()` function already mentioned by @Gajus, also a `txid_current_if_assigned()` function, which returns “NULL if no [transaction] ID is assigned yet” allowing you “to avoid unnecessary consumption of an XID” (which is the problem that @Gajus was hinting at in his answer from 2018).

In fact, since PostgreSQL 13, these `txid_`-prefixed functions are [deprecated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT) in favor of `pg_current_xact_id()` and `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()`.

The reason that, if you just want to find out *if* you are currently inside of a transaction, it's better to use `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()` than `pg_current_xact_id()` is because, as a rule of thumb, you want to avoid unnecessary XID consumption. GitLab, for instance, [ran into problems](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/09/29/why-we-spent-the-last-month-eliminating-postgresql-subtransactions/) because they used save points too extensively.

However, a caveat also applies to `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()`. It will return `NULL` as long as nothing has been written within your transaction, because PostgreSQL doesn't assign a transaction ID until a write operation occurs. A possible workaround is to create a temporary table that is bound the transaction:

```sql
SELECT pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned() IS NOT NULL AS is_transaction;
```

```
 is_transaction
----------------
 f
(1 row)
```

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  -- Making it explicitly READ WRITE won't make a difference.

SELECT pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned() IS NOT NULL AS is_transaction;
```

```
 is_transaction
----------------
 f
(1 row)
```

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a (b int) ON COMMIT DROP;

SELECT pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned() IS NOT NULL AS is_transaction;
```

```
 is_transaction
----------------
 t
(1 row)
```

There you have it.

If you where to run the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE … ON COMMIT DROP` statement outside of a transaction, it will have disappeared by the end of the implicit transaction that each mutating statement (in auto-commit-mode) is executed in.

**Edit 1:** Do note that you cannot wrap this logic into a function or procedure, because the function/procedure call statement will be wrapped in an implicit transaction, and thus your `am_i_inside_a_transaction()` function would always return `TRUE`.

**Edit 2:** I want to make it clear that, besides the informational value of my answer, I do as of yet believe the comparing timestamps method from [@Gajus his own answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/208375/79909) to be superior to the `pg_current_xact_id_if_assigned()` method. And his method can be made even more explicit by using `transaction_timestamp()` instead of `now()`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION in_transaction() RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE SQL
RETURN transaction_timestamp() != statement_timestamp()
;
```

```sql
SELECT in_transaction();
```

```sql
 in_transaction
----------------
 f
(1 row)
```

```sql
BEGIN;
SELECT in_transaction();
```

```
 in_transaction
----------------
 t
(1 row)
```

A caveat applies here too, though, since `statement_timestamp()` is “the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client”. That means that if you are to nest the above function call in another function, the function will always return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, psql and executing the same statement from within an application yields different results. I tried a Tcl script and DBeaver.

Statement: `SELECT now(), statement_timestamp();`

psql: `2021-05-07 13:31:10.135851+02 | 2021-05-07 13:31:10.135851+02`

DBeaver: `2021-05-07 13:31:00.633784+02|2021-05-07 13:31:00.633913+02`

Tcl script: `{now {2021-05-07 13:24:54.659837+02} statement_timestamp {2021-05-07 13:24:54.65985+02}}`

So in psql now() and statement_timestamp() are identical when not in a transaction, while in the others the two values vary a little bit, roughly 100 microseconds.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. If you want to know what causes such behaviour, you should probably ask a separate question.

Comment: It doesn't, but provides a helpful warning that the previous answer may  not always work.

Comment: @HolgerJakobs, Are you sure that DBeaver and the Tcl Postgres library do not wrap your statements within a transaction with the settings you used? I'v never use DBeaver, but [their docs suggest](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Auto-and-Manual-Commit-Modes/) that, if you were running in “Manual commit” mode, it will precede your statements with a `START TRANSACTION` statement.